# Graph apprequests

Tags: facebook, graph, facebook-graph-api

I have problems with apprequests, where I define the recipient?

https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/apprequests?message=MESSAGE&data=&TOKEN&method=post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an App-generated request which means the request will be sent to the user you specified in your url `USER_ID`.

More about user- and app-generated requests can be found in the Requests section of the [Social Channels document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/channels/).

Comment: Please **read** the document I linked to, `User-generated requests: These requests are confirmed by a user’s explicit action on a request dialog.` so you can't send a user-generated requests programatically.

Answer (score 1):

An app to user request works very different than a user to user request sent via dialog.

App to User Requests are only available for Canvas apps, not websites, as accepting a request will direct the user to the Canvas Page URL of the app that sent the Request. App to User Requests do not create notifications, though they do appear in the App and Games Dashboard and increment an app bookmark counter, similar to User to User Requests.

You can post a apprequest for a user by issuing an HTTP POST request to /USER_ID/apprequests with the app access_token.

Important to note is you need app access token and not user access token.